# PySimpleGUI window update frame layout based on event from combobox

Tags: python-3.x, window, pysimplegui

I want to change a row of layout within a frame by changing event from combobox.
And change back when first value from combobox is triggered.

When the window starts, it looks like below.
[image]

When user change value in combobox from Class A to Class B.

[image]

Window updates with new frame showing Class B.

[image]

window[key-name].update(visible=True) does't work with frame?

The Code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("Reddit")

layout = [ [sg.Frame(
          layout=[
[sg.Text("ID:",key='-ID-',size=(10, 1)),
sg.InputText(key='-section-id-',size=(10, 1), tooltip=" Define an id")
],
[
    sg.Frame(
        layout=[
            [sg.Text("Student:",key='-student-',size=(10, 1)),
             sg.InputText(default_text="25",key='-Class1-',size=(5, 1)),
             sg.InputText(default_text="25",key='-Class2-',size=(5, 1)),
             sg.Combo(['Yes', 'No'],key='-Yes&No-', default_value='Yes'),
             sg.Combo(['A','B'],key='-A-B-',default_value='A')],
        ],
        title="Student I",
        relief=sg.RELIEF_GROOVE,
    )
],
[
    sg.Frame(
        layout=[
             [sg.Text("Student in A:",key='-IN-A-',size=(10, 1)),
             sg.InputText(default_text="20",key='-MALE-',size=(5, 1), tooltip=" Number of males in Class A"),
             sg.InputText(default_text="30",key='-FEMALE-',size=(5, 1), tooltip=" Number of females in Class A"),
             sg.Combo(['A1','A2'],key='-A1-A2-',default_value='A1'),
             sg.Combo(['Class A','Class B'],key='-CLASS-A-CLASS-B-',default_value='Class A',size=(8,1),
             enable_events=True)],
        ],
        title="Main class",
        relief=sg.RELIEF_GROOVE,
    )
],
# [
#     sg.Frame(
#         layout=[
#             [sg.Text("Student in B:", key='-IN-A-', size=(10, 1)),
#              sg.InputText(default_text="10", key='-FEMALE-', size=(5, 1), tooltip=" Number of females in Class B"),
#              sg.InputText(default_text="30", key='-FEMALE-', size=(5, 1), tooltip=" Number of males in Class B"),
#              sg.Combo(['B1', 'B2'], key='-B1-B2-', default_value='B1'),
#              sg.Combo(['Class A', 'Class B'], key='-CLASS-A-CLASS-B-', default_value='Class B', size=(8, 1),
#                       enable_events=True)],
#         ],
#         title="Main class",
#         relief=sg.RELIEF_GROOVE,
#     )
# ]

          ],
          title="Add an ID",
          relief=sg.RELIEF_GROOVE,
             )
              ],
[sg.Push(),sg.Button('Add ID',key='-Add-ID-',size=(10,1),font=("",8,"bold")),
 sg.Button('Cancel',key='-Cancel-',size=(5,1),font=("",8,"bold"))]
 ]

window = sg.Window("Add an ID", layout, resizable=True,  keep_on_top=True)

while True:
   event, values = window.read()
   if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == '-Cancel-':
      sys.exit()
   if event == '-CLASS-A-CLASS-B-' and values['-CLASS-A-CLASS-B-'] == 'Class B':
      window.refresh()
      print('Tested ok!'+' '+values['-CLASS-A-CLASS-B-'])
window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following simple and short Code demo how to switching between Frames by Combo event.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Combo(["Class A", "Class B"], default_value="Class A", enable_events=True, key='COMBO')],
    [sg.Frame("Class A", [[sg.Text("This is the Class A Frame")]], key='Class A'),
     sg.Frame("Class B", [[sg.Text("This is the Class B Frame")]], key='Class B', visible=False)],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "COMBO":
        selection = values[event]
        if selection in ("Class A", "Class B"):
            window["Class A"].update(visible=(selection=="Class A"))
            window["Class B"].update(visible=(selection=="Class B"))

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Great @Jason. Simple and short demo and educational  :)